# Tool to determine motherboard in Windows or Linux

Tags: linux, windows, motherboard

In Windows or Linux, is there a tool to determine the brand/model of your motherboard?
Something like [CPU-Z or GPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/cpuz.php) but instead listing the motherboard information.

Even when you open the case and LOOK at the motherboard it's unclear what the model number is, and sometimes even the brand name is hidden.

In my case, I have an ASUS P6T motherboard, but can't tell which of the 5 flavors of P6T it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Linux there is [lshw](http://ezix.org/project/wiki/HardwareLiSter). Example from my main computer:

```
    description: Desktop Computer
    product: P5K Premium
    vendor: System manufacturer
    version: System Version
    serial: System Serial Number
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.4 dmi-2.4 vsyscall64 vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=desktop uuid=C760001E-8C00-001E-47E3-001E8C8988CB
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: P5K Premium
       vendor: ASUSTeK Computer INC.
       physical id: 0
       version: Rev 1.xx
       serial: MS1C7CBA7701227
       slot: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: 0612 (03/19/2008)
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 1984KiB
          capabilities: isa pci pnp apm upgrade shadowing escd cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb ls120boot zipboot biosbootspecification
     *-cpu
          ...
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very sure with your question. 
You should even check it

- http://www.belarc.com/free_download.html
- http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Info/Mainboard-DMI-Information-Viewer.shtml
- http://download.cnet.com/Motherboard-Monitor/3000-2086_4-10518386.html
- http://www.webattack.com/get/aida32.shtml
- http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Info/

Also this article

- http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/article/236

For Linux, you can use "hwinfo"

- http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/how-to-see-which-motherboard-i-am-using-422812/

Answer (score 1):

For Windows there's Piriform's [Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy). On Linux, as hlovdal says, `sudo lshw` is good. Of it's not run as root, you don't get all the information.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure something like this exists. The major reason for this is that the motherboard is just a combination of other manufacturers parts so Windows doesn't really care who made it and I am not sure it even looks for that information. Windows just cares about what drivers it needs for the chipset, on board sound and video, usb ports ...